# Multiple colors for typed words in TextField in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

If it was a text I would write

```
Text("Hello ")+Text("world").foregroundColor(.yellow)
```

What can I do in a `TextField` / `TextEditor` ?

Answer (score 1):

I found an *horrible* SwiftUI solution:

```
@State private var text = "Hello world"

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
            
            text
                .split(separator: " ")
                .map {
                    if $0 == "world" {
                        return Text($0 + " ").foregroundColor(.red)
                    } else {
                        return Text($0 + " ")
                    }
                }
                .reduce(Text(""), +)
                .padding(.vertical, 8.5)
                .padding(.horizontal, 5)
        }
    }.padding()
}
```

Problem with this approach:

1. The text inside TextEditor has a padding
2. The background of TextEditor is white by default so I had to move it down in the ZStack, disabling the possibility to touch the Text in the text editor

Comment: I added a question for problem 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62848276/change-background-color-of-texteditor-in-swiftui