# Change background color of TextEditor in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

`TextEditor` seems to have a default white background. So the following is not working and it displayed as `white` instead of defined `red`:

```
var body: some View {
    TextEditor(text: .constant("Placeholder"))
        .background(Color.red)
}
```

Is it possible to change the color to a custom one?

Comment: On macOS, for me it worked the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65865881/14728668) accepted answer.

Comment: I figured out how to do this using the `.opacity` and `.background(Color.blue)` properties.  It's really easy and looks great.  To see the answer and a snapshot go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865182/transparent-background-for-texteditor-in-swiftui/77889162#77889162

Answer (score 200, accepted):

#### iOS 16

You should hide the default background to see your desired one:

```
TextEditor(text: .constant("Placeholder"))
    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden) // <- Hide it
    .background(.red) // To see this
```

---

#### iOS 15 and below

`TextEditor` is backed by `UITextView`. So you need to get rid of the `UITextView`'s `backgroundColor` first and then you can set any `View` to the `background`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            TextEditor(text: .constant("Placeholder"))
                .background(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Demo

[image]

<sub>You can find my simple trick for growing TextEditor [here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60039382/5623035)</sub>

Comment: To extend this question/answer - because SwiftUI also supports macOS apps, how would you do this same thing with a `TextEditor` based on `NSTextView`?

Comment: Genius, if only the folks at Apple could have done that for us!

Comment: Agree, I hope apple fix that soon but there will be no backward compatibility as always. So we should stick to this for a while unfortunately. @AntonínKarásek .

Comment: to answer with NSTextVIew on OS X, seems you dont. Been trying to do this for 2 days. Apple is so great setting a background color is advanced technology.

Comment: Am I the only one to see the danger of using `UITextView.appearance()`, which changes the configuration of `UITextView` for the whole app, as workaround?

Comment: If for whatever reason you can't do `UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear` in init(), inside onAppear() works for me on iOS 15.

Comment: To add to @maz, this does not work in `.task()`, only in `.onAppear()`.

Comment: This does not seem to work in iOS 16 beta 4.

Comment: @LimThyeChean I have added the working method for iOS 16

Comment: Doesn't work for me with `textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)` on iOS 16. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Is this working for you in dark mode on iPad? Cause for me the exact same code on iPhone is working, but on iPad and in dark mode, the background of the TextEditor is still black (.systemBackground)

Comment: I had a ZStack with Text (for placeholder functionality) and a TextEditor and even though the Text was visible (not the TextEditor) it's background was still leaking.     .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
did the job and fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

As many have stated, with iOS 16 you need to use `scrollContentBackground`. I created an extension method to handle both cases:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var editingText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $editingText)
            .transparentScrolling()
            .background(Color.red)
    }
}

public extension View {
    func transparentScrolling() -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            return scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        } else {
            return onAppear {
                UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This in only solution which fulfils every requirements (all iOS, all mode)

Answer (score 18):

**Pure SwiftUI solution on iOS and macOS**

colorMultiply is your friend.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var editingText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TextEditor(text: $editingText)
            .frame(width: 400, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .cornerRadius(3.0)
            .colorMultiply(.gray)
    }
}
```

Comment: This will overlay the text color

Comment: plus it's not working in dark mode..

Comment: not working in dark mode

Comment: Works for me, doesn't overlay the text color either. I don't have dark mode on my app so it's perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

**Update iOS 16 / SwiftUI 4.0**

You need to use `.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)` instead of `UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear`

https://twitter.com/StuFFmc/status/1556561422431174656

Warning: This is an iOS 16 only so you'll probably need some `if #available`  and potentially two different `TextEditor` component.

Comment: not working in the .dark mode

Comment: Actually, works also in dark mode @mgyky

Comment: Demo/Sample here: https://gitlab.com/stuffmc/TransparentText

Comment: For me it's also not working in dark mode...

Answer (score 9):

This works for me on macOS

```swift
extension NSTextView {
  open override var frame: CGRect {
    didSet {
      backgroundColor = .clear
      drawsBackground = true
    }
  }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {        
        TextEditor(text: $text)           
            .background(Color.red)    
    }
```

[Reference this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865182/transparent-background-for-texteditor-in-swiftui%29)

Comment: genius mate! most elegant answer and so few upvotes...

Answer (score 9):

**Ios 16**
Make sure to add    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden) this lines then background will apply

```
TextEditor(text:.constant(hint))
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
.background(.red) // To see this
```

This work for me

Answer (score 6):

```
extension View {
/// Layers the given views behind this ``TextEditor``.
    func textEditorBackground<V>(@ViewBuilder _ content: () -> V) -> some View where V : View {
        self
            .onAppear {
                UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
            }
            .background(content())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Alex!

Comment: You're welcome Tom. Check out some more View extensions here: https://github.com/rebeloper/Dot/blob/main/Sources/Dot/Extensions/View%2B.swift

Answer (score 6):

### To achieve this visual design here is the code I used.

[image]

### iOS 16

```
TextField(
    "free_form",
    text: $comment,
    prompt: Text("Type your feedback..."),
    axis: .vertical
)
.lineSpacing(10.0)
.lineLimit(10...)
.padding(16)
.background(Color.themeSeashell)
.cornerRadius(16)
```

### iOS 15

```
ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
    
    TextEditor(text: $comment)
        .padding()
        .focused($isFocused)
    
    if !isFocused {
        Text("Type your feedback...")
            .padding()
    }
}
.frame(height: 132)
.onAppear() {
    UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Custom Background color with SwiftUI on macOS

On macOS, unfortunately, you have to fallback to AppKit and wrap NSTextView.

You need to declare a view that conforms to [NSViewRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/nsviewrepresentable)

This should give you pretty much the same behaviour as SwiftUI's `TextEditor`-View and since the wrapped NSTextView does not draw its background, you can use the `.background`-ViewModifier to change the background

```
struct CustomizableTextEditor: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            NSScrollableTextViewRepresentable(text: $text, size: geometry.size)
        }
    }
    
}

struct NSScrollableTextViewRepresentable: NSViewRepresentable {
    typealias Representable = Self
    
    // Hook this binding up with the parent View
    @Binding var text: String
    var size: CGSize
    
    // Get the UndoManager
    @Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManger
    
    // create an NSTextView
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSScrollView {
        
        // create NSTextView inside NSScrollView
        let scrollView = NSTextView.scrollableTextView()
        let nsTextView = scrollView.documentView as! NSTextView
        
        // use SwiftUI Coordinator as the delegate
        nsTextView.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        // set drawsBackground to false (=> clear Background)
        // use .background-modifier later with SwiftUI-View
        nsTextView.drawsBackground = false
        
        // allow undo/redo
        nsTextView.allowsUndo = true
        
        return scrollView
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ scrollView: NSScrollView, context: Context) {
        // get wrapped nsTextView
        guard let nsTextView = scrollView.documentView as? NSTextView else {
            return
        }
        
        // fill entire given size
        nsTextView.minSize = size
        
        // set NSTextView string from SwiftUI-Binding
        nsTextView.string = text
    }
    
    // Create Coordinator for this View
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    // Declare nested Coordinator class which conforms to NSTextViewDelegate
    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSTextViewDelegate {
        var parent: Representable // store reference to parent
        
        init(_ textEditor: Representable) {
            self.parent = textEditor
        }
        
        // delegate method to retrieve changed text
        func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
            // check that Notification.name is of expected notification
            // cast Notification.object as NSTextView

            guard notification.name == NSText.didChangeNotification,
                let nsTextView = notification.object as? NSTextView else {
                return
            }
            // set SwiftUI-Binding
            parent.text = nsTextView.string
        }
        
        // Pass SwiftUI UndoManager to NSTextView
        func undoManager(for view: NSTextView) -> UndoManager? {
            parent.undoManger
        }

        // feel free to implement more delegate methods...
        
    }
    
}
```

#### Usage

```
ContenView: View {
    @State private var text: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Enter your text here:")
            CustomizableTextEditor(text: $text)
                .background(Color.red)
        }
            .frame(minWidth: 600, minHeight: 400)

    }
}
```

#### Edit:

- Pass reference to SwiftUI UndoManager so that default undo/redo actions are available.
- Wrap NSTextView in NSScrollView so that it is scrollable. Set `minSize` property of NSTextView to enclosing SwiftUIView-Size so that it fills the entire allowed space.

<strike>Caveat: Only first line of this custom TextEditor is clickable to enable text editing.</strike>

Comment: I voted you up since it works with macOS as well but there is far too much overhead

Comment: Yes, it's a lot of code for simply changing the background color, but a fun exercise though. I tried your solution, but `.colorMultiply()` actually blends all colours together (so e.g. if you multiply by Color.clear you won't see anything). Or I possibly missed something, but your provide code is not working for me

Comment: This one works well on macOS and is small and simple: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65865881/345258

Comment: Superb! Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

[Using the Introspect library](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect), you can use .introspectTextView for changing the background color.

```
TextEditor(text: .constant("Placeholder"))
.cornerRadius(8)
.frame(height: 100)
.introspectTextView { textView in
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.red)
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na2lk.jpg)

Comment: Honestly, I find this more "correct" than the accepted answer because the accepted answer changes the text field appearance for the entire application.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore in macOS Ventura.

Comment: this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mojtaba's answer (the approved answer). It works in most cases. However, if you run into this error:

"Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties"

when trying to use the `init{ ... }` method, try adding `UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear` to `.onAppear{ ... }` instead.

Example:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {

        ...

    }
    .onAppear {
        UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

Comment: this is also will not work for dark mode.

Comment: Not working in dark mode, iOS 14+

Answer (score 1):

#### iOS 13+

Well, this soultion seems to work with me in iOS 16 and some earlier versions as well.

```swift
TextEditor(text: $text)
    .scrollContentBackgroundHidden()
    .background(Style.backgroundColor) // Color works with iOS 16
    .textEditorBackground {
        Color(Style.backgroundColor) // Color works with earlier versions
    }
```

With the help of both extensions to support earlier versions as well

```swift
extension View {
    /// Hides the standard system background of the view.
    /// 
    func scrollContentBackgroundHidden() -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            return self.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }

    /// Layers the given views behind this ``TextEditor``.
    ///
    func textEditorBackground<V>(@ViewBuilder _ content: () -> V) -> some View where V : View {
        self
            .onAppear {
                UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
            }
            .background(content())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change TextEditor background color, this modifier works well for me. Just we need to consider both the cases of iOS 16 and below.

```
 extension View {
        func textEditorBackground(_ content: Color) -> some View {
            if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                return self.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                    .background(content)
            } else {
                UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
                return self.background(content)
            }
        }
    }

TextEditor(text: $message)
.modifier(TextEditorBackground(color: Color("PrimaryGray")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddCommentView: View {
    
    init() {
        UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    var body: some View {
           VStack {
                    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                        TextEditor(text: $viewModel.commentText)
                            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                    } else {
                        TextEditor(text: $viewModel.commentText)
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.blue)
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1)
                )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the `UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear` trick in IOS 16,

only works for the first time you open the view  and the effect disappear when the second time it loads.

So we need to provide both ways in the app. Answer from [StuFF mc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73275264/10859229) works.

```
 var body: some View {
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        mainView.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
    } else {
        mainView.onAppear {
            UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }
}

// rename body to mainView
var mainView: some View {
    TextEditor(text: $notes).background(Color.red)              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution as well and here is what I have figured it out.

I think a more proper way is that we can just create a custom wrapper for `UITextView` to remove the default background color, and then we apply the style in View instead of interacting with the UIKit stuff inside the View.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct TextViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let uiTextView = UITextView()
        uiTextView.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        uiTextView.backgroundColor = .clear
        return uiTextView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiTextView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiTextView.text = text
    }
}
```

```
@State private var description = ""

TextViewWrapper(text: $description)
    .frame(height: 72)
    .padding(
        EdgeInsets(
            top: 8,
            leading: 8,
            bottom: 8,
            trailing: 8
        )
    )
    .background(Color.secondary.opacity(0.2))
    .cornerRadius(12)
```